# Android Studio Volume button pressed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onkeydown

I have a function that do something when I press the volume button three times and it works fine.

The problem is that I want it to work in every activity and fragment in the program when the volume button is pressed three times and not only in the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the code of the listener into a separate abstract class and make extends of this class for all your activities

Create a **BaseActivity.class** with the following code

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            // Do something when volume down clicked!
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in your activities

```
public class OtherActivity extends BaseActivity {
}
```